# mysql where count(column_name) = 1?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, sql-delete, mysql-error-1111

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT k_id, COUNT(k_id) AS k_count 
FROM template_keyword_link 
WHERE k_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY k_id;
```

This query returns something like
1 | 6
2 | 1
3 | 4
4 | 1
5 | 9

I want to add something like `AND COUNT(k_id) = 1`
so I end up with
2 | 1
4 | 1

However I get invalid use a group function.

How would I go about doing this?

---

**Update:**

The other part to my question is.

Can this be used as a delete statement?

something like

```
DELETE FROM 
template_keyword_link tkl
LEFT JOIN keywords k
ON tkl.k_id = k.k_id
WHERE tkl.k_id 
IN(SELECT k_id, COUNT(k_id) AS k_count 
FROM template_keyword_link 
WHERE k_id IN(1,2)
GROUP BY k_id
HAVING k_count = 1);
```

I get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;

---

**So based on feedback i have altered this to use**

```
DELETE tkl, k FROM 
template_keyword_link tkl
LEFT JOIN keywords k
ON tkl.k_id = k.k_id
WHERE tkl.k_id 
IN(SELECT k_id 
FROM template_keyword_link 
WHERE k_id IN(1,2)
GROUP BY k_id
HAVING COUNT(k_id) = 1);
```

However now I am getting

> You can't specify target table 'tkl' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Could you add the exact query that gives you the error?

Comment: what u want is show the id , whose count is 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`WHERE` clause is applied before the `COUNT(*)` has been calculated, so you need in `HAVING`, that is applied after.

```
  SELECT k_id,
         COUNT(k_id) AS k_count 
    FROM template_keyword_link 
   WHERE k_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY k_id
  HAVING k_count = 1
```

See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

** UPD **:

TIAS ;-) btw, the query **syntactically** seems fine for me, **BUT** did not you forget to specify `template_keyword_link` and `keywords` join condition clause? Does mysql give you any errors?

Comment: Edited the query to include them ;)

But as you can see, Im still getting an error.

Comment: because `IN` expects to get only one column, while you're giving 2. Move `count(*)` to `having`.

Comment: yes, you cannot select from the table you're modifying now :-S

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`having`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php) clause which happens *after* grouping (the `where` clause is before grouping):

```
SELECT k_id, COUNT(k_id) AS k_count 
FROM template_keyword_link 
WHERE k_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY k_id
HAVING COUNT(k_id) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested subquery is a simple solution.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT k_id, COUNT(k_id) AS k_count 
    FROM template_keyword_link 
    WHERE k_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
    GROUP BY k_id 
  ) inner
WHERE inner.k_count = 1
```

Comment: HAVING is simpler and more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
SELECT k_id, COUNT(k_id) AS k_count 
FROM template_keyword_link 
WHERE k_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY k_id
HAVING ( COUNT(k_id) = 1 )
```